# jquery array of classes out of get object

Tags: jquery, arrays, class, get

```
<script>
var tmp
$.get("http://intranet/Lists/Software/Kennisgebied.aspx?FilterField1=Directorie&FilterValue1=P:\airpex", 
    function(response) { 
        alert(response);
        tmp = $(response).filter("ms-vb2").html();
        alert(tmp[1]);
    }
);
</script>
```

Hello I am trying to learn jquery, but i'm stuck.

What I want to do is get an array of the class "ms-vb2" out of response.

I want to get the text "1.0" in the TD tag.

```
 <td class="ms-vb2">1.0</td>
```

Tnx for your help and time

Answer (score 1):

I need your html response content to be sure, but it will looks something like:

```
var arr = $(response).find('.ms-vb2').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```